# Using fonts with Wordpress in different Browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, browser, google-font-api

So I've read that there is a bug on Chrome for Windows which cause bad rendering. Is this the same for Opera? And why isn't it working for IE?

Font: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Libre+Baskerville

Embedding:

```
wp_enqueue_style('fontbask', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,500,700,400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext');
```

CSS I've tried

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
```

Result:

[image]

Brwoser versions:

Opera 19.0.1326.63
Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m
Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16518
Firefox 26.0

I also tried to use font-face to include the fonts, which had exactly the same result.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LibreBaskerville';
    src: url('fonts/LibreBaskerville-Regular.otf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I downloaded the fonts @ http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/libre-baskerville?q[term]=baskerville&q[search_check]=Y
In this screenshot it doesn't look that bad, but you can see live here: http://www.citizen-science.at/wordpress/

I also found that the font from http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Libre+Baskerville is rendered as badly as well. So it seems it is a browser issues.

When I'm using my local fonts instead of Google fonts, IE is able to show it, but Opera and Chrome still don't

Comment: can you be specific about opera version?

Comment: As @Zeshan Khan Alvi said, what version of Opera? The old one that use Presto Engine (and no longer gets updates) or the new one Opera Next that use Webkit Engine ?

Answer (score 2):

Opera have issue in font rendering. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771629/opera-not-rendering-certain-characters-from-webfonts) will help you finding the solution. If `Google fonts` are not must use for you then i recommend [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) website for web font generation. This works awesomely with cross browser compatibility.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'libre_baskervilleregular';
    src: url('librebaskerville-webfont.eot');
    src: url('librebaskerville-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('librebaskerville-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('librebaskerville-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('librebaskerville-webfont.svg#libre_baskervilleregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Web fonts generated from [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Use this, these will work with cross browser compatibility including Opera.

good luck!

Comment: I actually downloaded the fonts at fontsquirrel, but still problems. So Opera has bugs I can't fix?

Comment: @4ndro1d which opera version you are using?

Comment: @4ndro1d css code you have posted have just one font format... where are the rest? you must pass different formats like otf,ttf,svg convert them on font squirrel and use them...

Comment: check this hope you will figure out something, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245141/using-otf-fonts-on-web-browsers

Comment: As I'm usin .otf font, which I downloaded from fontquirrel I guess i did everything right? I'm not having any problems with IE, only with Chrome and Opera